# Can't become leader of the Thieves Guild in Skyrim/Xbox One

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just finished all the special quests for each of the holds of Skyrim, and the quest "Under new Management" does not appear.

I am at the quest "Darkness Returns" of the principal arc.

Brynjolf keeps ignoring me every time i try to talk to him.

How do I proceed to become the leader of the Thieves Guild?

Answer (score 2):

You need to complete the quest [Darkness Returns](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Darkness_Returns) as it is listed as a prerequisite for the Guild Master ceremony [Under New Management](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Under_New_Management).

> Once you have completed all of the reputation quests and Darkness Returns, you will be told to talk to Brynjolf about becoming the new Guild Master.

Answer (score -1):

You need to go to baldy in the ragged flagon and ask him for a bedlam quest every time you do one a store appears in the flagon and once you have done them all you will become the guild master and receive the guild masters armour